# Approximating value of cdf integral

Tags: normal-distribution, indefinite-integrals, cumulative-distribution-functions

Approximate the cdf of a standard normal distribution.
How does one approximate the value of the integral that is involved since it's not directly solvable.
In the example below it's mentioned that $ 2\Phi(1)-1= 0.68$.
How is this approximate value obtained?
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deCL9.jpg)

Comment: We can always use numerical methods to compute definite integrals. The famous ones are the Trapezoidal Rule and Simpson's Rule.